# jQuery: Ho to make pressing enter on text box run a function?

Tags: jquery, html

I've been making the Mad Libs game from General Assembly, and I'm trying to split everything into its own files (.html, .css, .js) and add a bit more functionality.

In it, a function is run which produces a text box. You click a button, the value is saved and a new text box appears (these are not forms, just an input and a button).

Currently, pressing the button works, but I want to make it also work when I press enter while the text box is selected.

This is what I have tried:

```
$('input').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){
        nextPrompt();
    }
});
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamically generated elements, you can use the `$(document)` selector :

```
$(document).on("keydown", "input", function(event){
    if(event.which == 13) {
        nextPrompt();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok yeah, this has worked great :) Will this then be because the function I call adds the input element to the HTML?
Thanks